# Prevent certain classes to call certain methods using Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I plan to give method calling privileges to certain classes in my program using Attributes but I just have no clude how to.

For example, here is what I want my `Customer` class to look like:

```
[ForbiddenMethodsAttr(listOfMyForbiddenMethods)]
public class Customer
{
    public Customer { }
}
```

And if I want to call a given function, the intellisense should warm me that I can't, The reason I want to do this is because calling those functions may cause some issues and not I'm the only one who will code this project but some friends as well. So if it is possible to write such an attribute, how to do it?

Comment: Sounds like you basically need to write a Roslyn code analyzer. This ability isn't part of the regular C# language.

Comment: Eh so I'm going for something bit too advanced for a casual attribute?

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't throw an exception on a method level attribute if a non-authorized call was made.

Comment: That was another thing I thought of, but it looked a bit weird. Looks like not that weird after all.

Comment: You should really consider your architecture here too. If some of these code modules cause unintended side-effects, then it should be explicit what is going to happen. You may also want to consider scoping classes/methods with private/internal/etc. to prevent unintended usage.

Comment: I think it would look weird no matter how you did it, if you are trying to restrict method access with an attribute.

I think DavidG is correct. Maybe an architecture change is in order in this case.

Comment: @DavidG The idea is that Admins can do more than Customers (of course) and we planned to just deny some calls for a Customer class. Shall we reorganize and use interfaces for these methods?

Comment: Make the classes (or certain methods, if you need to expose class instances) `internal` and make the other contributors write their code in different assemblies. Or better yet, refactor the whole thing so the internals are internal and the public class members are actually safe to use. That's a big part of why classes exist: To keep the tender squishy bits safe inside. You're reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: That's what we shall do, yes. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Just put the common methods for both admin and regular customer in a base class, then inherit that base class (Customer) in a CustomerAdmin and CustomerUser class which define special cases for those customer types.  That way, only the methods which are allowed are exposed to the different customer types.

Comment: I had some similar magic trick question here with this project but I start to realise that 99% of these cases are related to poor design :D High time we gave this stuff a second thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mark the methods as obsolete and then anyone calling them will get a compiler warning (though not error). Its not elegant, but neither is attempting to restrict method calls without using scoping conventions.

Comment: Reasonable and answer to the question, though I think I have the lads reconsider the whole structure in this case. All in all thanks for your advice!